# Android Virtual Devices (AVD) resolution not correct after downloading Android 5.1.1 for SDK

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

The story is that I developed an Android program with Android 4.4.2.  But some problems was found after installing the program to a device with Android 5.1.1.  So I tried to download Android 5.1.1 for my SDK to debug the problem.  Then the AVD I kept on using becomes like a mess no matter I changed to different configuration (see picture 1).  My AVD configuration is as picture 2.

Hope someone could help...  Thank you so much!

Picture 1
[image: picture 1]

Picture 2
[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 0):

Got a temporary way to solve it and don't know if it is correct.

Set the skin to "no skin".

There is another problem happened now.  The control bar of that window shows out of the screen. It makes the window cannot be moved.  Anyway, I can continue my development job in this way...